# Is std::is_convertible co-variant or contra-variant?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), `std::is_convertible< From, To >` should behave as if following imaginary function is well formed:

```
template < class To, class From >
To test() {
    return std::declval< From >();
}
```

This implies, that `std::is_convertible< From, To >::value` shall evaluate to `true` if `To` is covariant with `From` (in other words, when `From` is base class of `To`, `std::is_convertible< From, To >::value` should evaluate to `true`).

Let's say that we have two classes.

```
struct Base {};

struct Derived : public Base {};
```

Now, if we call imaginary test method, both `test< Base*, Derived* >()` and `test< Derived*, Base* >()` will actually be well formed, because you can return pointer to derived class even though formal return type is pointer to base class. But result of `is_convertible< Base*, Derived* >` and `is_convertible< Derived*, Base* >` will differ (`std::is_convertible_v< Base*, Derived* >` is equal to false. Is the description of this trait accurate?

**EDIT**

Here is my attempt to implement `is_convertible` trait

```
template < class T, class U >
U convert() {
    return std::declval< T >();
}

template < class T, class U, bool isTVoid = std::is_void_v< T >, bool isUVoid = std::is_void_v< U >, class = void >
struct is_convertible_helper
    : public std::false_type {};

template < class T, class U >
struct is_convertible_helper< T, U, false, false, std::void_t< decltype(convert< T, U >()) > >
    : public std::true_type {};

template < class T, class U >
struct is_convertible_helper< T, U, false, true, void >
    : public std::false_type {};

template < class T, class U >
struct is_convertible_helper< T, U, true, false, void >
    : public std::false_type {};

template < class T, class U >
struct is_convertible_helper< T, U, true, true, void >
    : public std::true_type {};

template < class T, class U >
struct is_convertible
    : public is_convertible_helper< T, U > {};
```

Reason why I asked this question was the fact, that both `is_convertible< A*, B* >::value` and `is_convertible< B*, A* >::value` evaluated to `true`.

Comment: *"if To is covariant with From (in other words, when From is base class of To"* --- this is not what *covariant* means. *both `test< Base*, Derived* >()` and `test< Derived*, Base* >()` will actually be well formed* --- no, this is absolutely wrong. *because you can return pointer to derived class even though formal return type is pointer to base class* --- this has nothing to do with the question in hand,

Comment: Well, covariance means that you can return pointer to derived class from a function that returns pointer to base class. In this case, From is pointer to base class and To is pointer to derived class. Should I edit second column of question for clarification?

Comment: Covariance means that you have a **family** of type pairs, and the types in pairs **co-vary** within the family, that is, change together in the same direction (from base to derived). When you have just two types, there is nothing that varies, so no covariance.

Comment: The return statement is never in the immediate context, so that attempted implementation of `is_convertible` is wrong from the outset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> both `test< Base*, Derived* >()` and `test< Derived*, Base* >()` will actually be well formed.

Not true.

`test<Derived*, Base*>()` is not well formed since `Base*` cannot be converted to `Derived*`.

See the problem at https://ideone.com/N73ROY.

> But result of `is_convertible< Base*, Derived* >` and `is_convertible< Derived*, Base* >` will differ (`std::is_convertible_v< Base*, Derived* >` is equal to false)

That is the correct behavior.

> Is the description of this trait accurate?

Yes.

---

Your confusion stemmed from the first statement. Since, that is not correct, the rest of the answers should make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from type A to type B and a subtype relation between type A and type B are very distinct things.

While it is true that if A is a subtype of B then B is convertible to A (well, there might be slicing, and assuming copy ctors are available etc. but in practice you would convert a B& to an A&), the opposite direction is certainly not true. `int` and `double` are inter-convertible and are obviously not subtypes of each other.

So I think you're kind of off-base trying to relate these concepts - without going into details.